# "Diabolic" vs. "Diabolical"

Tags: word-usage, suffixes

Is there a context where **diabolic** is not a synonym of **diabolical**, or vice versa?

> Diabolic's definition:
>
> adj. Showing wickedness typical of a devil.
>
> Diabolical's definiton
>
> adj. Of, concerning, or characteristic of the devil; satanic.

Diversely from **diabolical**, **diabolic**'s definition seems to be more strictly related to the Devil or his likeness, as, for example, in "the diabolic glamour of Nazism", I think.

Answer (score 7):

In a word, No.

Definitions vary from dictionary to dictionary; some dictionaries don't even give *diabolic*; some distinguish the two words quite differently. Collins English Dictionary (online) for instance:

> **Diabolic**: 1. of, relating to, or proceeding from the devil; satanic 2. befitting a devil; extremely cruel or wicked; fiendish 3. very difficult or unpleasant
>
> **Diabolical** (*informal*): 1. excruciatingly bad; outrageous 2. (*intensifier*) ⇒ a diabolical liberty

There is no consistent difference in use. There are scores, perhaps hundreds of these *-ic*, *-ical* doublets in English; offhand, the only pair I can think of which regularly exhibits a distinction is *historic, historical*.

This does not prohibit you (or, apparently, lexicographers) from deciding on a consistent pattern of distinction in your own use. It might be very useful in, say, a monograph on diabolism. But unless you explicitly define the distinction nobody will notice.

Comment: *No* for this particular word *for most people, in most contexts*. But as with *economic/-ical, electric/-ical*, if a useful semantic distinction *can* be made, there's every possibility that if the two forms hang around for long enough, most likely eventually that distinction *will* be made by many/most speakers.